# iOS App Rejected with missing Push Notification entitlements

Tags: ios, certificate

I worked for an update version for an application where there was no Push Notifications in the old version and now enable these services in this Version. Having all done and working perfectly both in Development,Distribution as well as Adhoc Distribution. But Apple rejected the App saying that you app has one or more issues Missing Push Notification Entilements and so on.

I have checked the Production and Development profiles for the aps-environment key and both the certificates having this key.No where having any problem with the Push notifications and my AppID also having this services enabled.

Unable to find out where the fault is please let me have some guidance over this.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the `UIBackgroundModes` dictionary in your `info.plist` contains `remote-notification`

[image]

Also, check that `Background Modes` capabilities are properly set.

[image]